# Can I transform this asynchronous java network API into a monadic representation (or something else idiomatic)?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I've been given a java api for connecting to and communicating over a proprietary bus using a callback based style. I'm currently implementing a proof-of-concept application in scala, and I'm trying to work out how I might produce a slightly more idiomatic scala interface.

A typical (simplified) application might look something like this in Java:

```
    DataType type = new DataType();
    BusConnector con = new BusConnector();
    con.waitForData(type.getClass()).addListener(new IListener<DataType>() {
        public void onEvent(DataType t) {
            //some stuff happens in here, and then we need some more data
            con.waitForData(anotherType.getClass()).addListener(new IListener<anotherType>() {
                public void onEvent(anotherType t) {
                    //we do more stuff in here, and so on
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //now we've got the behaviours set up we call
    con.start();
```

In scala I can obviously define an implicit conversion from (T => Unit) into an IListener, which certainly makes things a bit simpler to read:

```
implicit def func2Ilistener[T](f: (T => Unit)) : IListener[T] = new IListener[T]{
  def onEvent(t:T) = f
}

val con = new BusConnector
con.waitForData(DataType.getClass).addListener( (d:DataType) => {
  //some stuff, then another wait for stuff
  con.waitForData(OtherType.getClass).addListener( (o:OtherType) => {
    //etc
  })
})
```

Looking at this reminded me of both scalaz promises and f# async workflows.

My question is this:

Can I convert this into either a for comprehension or something similarly idiomatic (I feel like this should map to actors reasonably well too)

Ideally I'd like to see something like:

```
for(
  d <- con.waitForData(DataType.getClass);
  val _ = doSomethingWith(d);
  o <- con.waitForData(OtherType.getClass)
  //etc
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a `for` comprehension for this, I'd recommend looking at the Scala Language Specification for how for comprehensions are expanded to `map`, `flatMap`, etc. This will give you some clues about how this structure relates to what you've already got (with nested calls to `addListener`).  You can then add an implicit conversion from the return type of the `waitForData` call to a new type with the appropriate `map`, `flatMap`, etc methods that delegate to `addListener`.

**Update**

I think you can use `scala.Responder[T]` from the standard library:

Assuming the class with the `addListener` is called `Dispatcher[T]`:

```
trait Dispatcher[T] {
  def addListener(listener: IListener[T]): Unit
}

trait IListener[T] {
  def onEvent(t: T): Unit
} 

implicit def dispatcher2Responder[T](d: Dispatcher[T]):Responder[T] = new Responder[T} {
  def respond(k: T => Unit) = d.addListener(new IListener[T] {
    def onEvent(t:T) = k
  })
}
```

You can then use this as requested

```
for(
  d <- con.waitForData(DataType.getClass);
  val _ = doSomethingWith(d);
  o <- con.waitForData(OtherType.getClass)
  //etc
) ()
```

See [the Scala wiki](http://scala.sygneca.com/libs/responder) and [this presentation](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/comet-like_scala/Comet-style%20Web%20Applications%20in%20Scala.pdf) on using `Responder[T]` for a Comet chat application.

Comment: Scalaz provides `Monad[Responder]`, so you legitimately have a monad instance if you do what Ben Lings suggests here. Also, `Responder` is a kind of "universal monad" in that you can implement any other monad in terms of it.

Comment: Responder gave me precisely the correct behaviour, although for some reason I had to use `def onEvent(t:T) = k(t)` instead of just ` = k`

Answer (score 3):

I have very little Scala experience, but if I were implementing something like this I'd look to leverage the actor mechanism rather than using callback listener classes. Actors were made for asynchronous communication, they nicely separate those different parts of your app for you. You can also have them send messages to multiple listeners.

We'll have to wait for a "real" Scala programmer to flesh this idea out, though. ;)